# How can I connect to Hedera Testnet using web3.js or ethers.js?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, hedera-hashgraph, hedera

​
I would like to interact with the Hedera Testnet using web3.js or ethers.js. How can I do this?
​
I have previously interacted with Hedera Testnet using `hedera-sdk-js`,
for example using the following code:
​

```js
import {
    AccountBalanceQuery, 
    Client
} from "@hashgraph/sdk";
​
const client = new Client({
    network: "testnet"
});
​
const accountId = '0.0.3996280';
const balance = await new AccountBalanceQuery()
    .setAccountId(accountId)
    .execute(client);
    
console.log(
    `Balance of ${accountId} in Tinybars:`,
    balance.hbars.toTinybars().toString(10)
);
​
```

​
How can I do the equivalent of the above in web3.js/ ethers.js?

Answer (score 5):

#### To connect via viem

(1)
First, obtain an RPC endpoint URL,
which is detailed over at [How can I connect to Hedera Testnet over RPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76153290/194982).

Once you have gotten that, substitute `${RPC_URL}` in the code examples below with that value.

(2)
Install viem:
​

```bash
npm install viem
```

​(3) Then define a `viem.Chain` instance for Hedera Testnet:

```js
import { defineChain } from 'viem';

const hederaTestnetChain = defineChain({
    id: 0x128,
    name: 'HederaTestnet',
    nativeCurrency: {
        symbol: 'ℏ',
        name: 'HBAR',
        decimals:  18,
    },
    rpcUrls: {
        default: {
            http: ['${RPC_URL}'],
        },
    },
    blockExplorers: {
        default: {
            name: 'Hashscan',
            url: 'https://hashscan.io/testnet'
        },
    },
    contracts: {},
});
```

(4)
Then use the following script to establish a connection
to the RPC endpoint using `viem.createPublicClient`,
and query `eth_blockNumber` with it:

```js
import { createPublicClient, http } from 'viem';

const web3Client = createPublicClient({
  chain: hederaTestnetChain,
  transport: http(),
});

const blockNumber = await web3Client.getBlockNumber();
    console.log('block number', blockNumber);
```

Answer (score 3):

#### To connect using **ethers.js**

(1)
First, obtain an RPC endpoint URL,
which is detailed over at [How can I connect to Hedera Testnet over RPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76153290/194982).
​
Once you have gotten that, substitute `${RPC_URL}` in the code examples below with that value.

(2)​
Install ethers.js:
​

```bash
npm install ethers@v5
```

(3)​
Then use the following script to establish a connection
to the RPC endpoint using `ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider`,
and query `eth_blockNumber` with it:
​

```js
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
​
const web3Provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider({
    url: '${RPC_URL}',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
});
​
async function main() {
    web3Provider.getBlockNumber()
        .then((blockNumber) => {
            console.log('block number', blockNumber);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
​
    web3Provider.getBalance(
        '0x00000000000000000000000000000000003cfa78')
        .then((balance) => {
            console.log('balance', balance.toBigInt());
        })
        .catch(console.error);
}
​
main();
​
```

​

Answer (score 2):

@bguiz answer should do it. There is also this tutorial that shows how you can do this with ethers.js along with a wallet like MetaMask.

https://youtu.be/mhqQToUEMBs?t=274

Here's a link to the code from the video, which is a function that you can reuse to connect a Hedera network (testnet/mainnet/previewnet) using Ethers.
https://github.com/ed-marquez/hedera-example-metamask-counter-dapp/blob/master/src/components/hedera/walletConnect.js

The code is also shown below.

1. You start by creating a new ethers provider
2. Then defined the `chainId` of the network you want to connect to (testnet/mainnet/previewnet). If you're using a wallet like MetaMask, you can optionally switch to a Hedera network programatically, and then you can specify the JSON-RPC and network explorer URLs
3. Obtain the selected account

   ```
   import { ethers } from "ethers";
    const network = "testnet";

    async function walletConnectFcn() {
        console.log(`\n=======================================`);

    // ETHERS PROVIDER
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any");

    // SWITCH TO HEDERA TEST NETWORK
    console.log(`- Switching network to the Hedera ${network}...`);
    let chainId;
    if (network === "testnet") {
        chainId = "0x128";
    } else if (network === "previewnet") {
        chainId = "0x129";
    } else {
        chainId = "0x127";
    }

    await window.ethereum.request({
        method: "wallet_addEthereumChain",
        params: [
            {
                chainName: `Hedera ${network}`,
                chainId: chainId,
                nativeCurrency: { name: "HBAR", symbol: "ℏℏ", decimals: 18 },
                rpcUrls: [`https://${network}.hashio.io/api`],
                blockExplorerUrls: [`https://hashscan.io/${network}/`],
            },
        ],
    });
    console.log("- Switched ✅");

    // CONNECT TO ACCOUNT
    console.log("- Connecting wallet...");
    let selectedAccount;
    await provider
        .send("eth_requestAccounts", [])
        .then((accounts) => {
            selectedAccount = accounts[0];
            console.log(`- Selected account: ${selectedAccount} ✅`);
        })
        .catch((connectError) => {
            console.log(`- ${connectError.message.toString()}`);
            return;
        });

    return [selectedAccount, provider, network];
   ```

   }

   export default walletConnectFcn;

Answer (score 2):

#### To connect using **web3.js**

(1)
First, obtain an RPC endpoint URL,
which is detailed over at [How can I connect to Hedera Testnet over RPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76153290/194982).
​
Once you have gotten that, substitute `${RPC_URL}` in the code examples below with that value.

(2)
Install web3.js:
​

```bash
npm install web3
```

​
(3)
Then use the following script to establish a connection
to the RPC endpoint using `Web3.providers.HttpProvider`,
and query `eth_blockNumber` with it:
​

```js
import Web3 from 'web3';
​
const web3Provider = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('${RPC_URL}'), {
    headers: [{
        name: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', value: '*'
    }],
    keepalive: true,
    withCredentials: false,
});
​
async function main() {
    web3Provider.eth.getBlockNumber()
        .then((blockNumber) => {
            console.log('block number', blockNumber);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
​
    web3Provider.eth.getBalance(
        '0x00000000000000000000000000000000003cfa78')
        .then((balance) => {
            console.log('balance', balance);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
}
​
main();
​
```