# How can I obtain a block number programmatically on Hedera?

Tags: rpc, hedera-hashgraph, hedera

I understand from [HIP-415: Introduction Of Blocks](https://hips.hedera.com/hip/hip-415),
that Hedera now has blocks,
and they're based on timestamps of the transactions
being grouped together into "record files"
which are an artefact of how they are ingested into the Hedera mirror nodes
(from the Hedera consensus nodes).
Essentially all transactions that are inside the same record file
are considered to be in the same block as well,
and these blocks are produced approximately every 2 seconds.

Is there a way that I can convert a date (timestamp) into a block number?
My objective is to be able to invoke `eth_getBlockByNumber`,
and I need work out the first parameter for that RPC request
based on timestamp.

```bash
curl -s -X POST \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"2","method":"eth_getBlockByNumber","params":[MY_BLOCK_NUM, false]}' \
    http://localhost:7546
```

(Need to work out `MY_BLOCK_NUM` in the ^ command above.)

For example, here's [block 4507206](https://hashscan.io/testnet/block/4507206),
which corresponds to the record file `2023-05-10T08_27_52.012122604Z.rcd.gz`,
and contains all transactions between
`08:27:52.0121` and `08:27:53.7004` in UTC today.
Suppose I **did not** know both what the block number was,
or what the record file was.
I only have a single timestamp,
and I want to find the corresponding block number from it.
How can I do this (programmatically)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the Unix timestamp for the date and time that you need. Use the `-u` flag if you want to specify the date/ time in UTC (otherwise default to the timezone on your computer).
​

```bash
TIMESTAMP=$(date -u -j -f "%F %T" "2023-05-10 08:27:52" "+%s")
```

​
(Sample result: `1683707272`)

Next, make an API request to the Hedera mirror node API:

- `/api/v1/blocks` - Responds with a list of blocks
- `timestamp=gte:${TIMESTAMP}` - Use this to specify the timestamp that you have from the previous step. The `gte` is a filter to say that you only want block whose timestamp is greater than or equal to the one you have specified.
- `limit=1` and `order=asc` - These combine with the above to further sort and filter the query such that it only returns the *first* block that comes *after* the specified timestamp.
  ​

```bash
curl -s "https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/blocks?limit=1&order=asc&timestamp=gte:${TIMESTAMP}" | jq
```

​
We repeat the same command as above, but this time extract the blocknumber out of the full response object using a `jq` path.
​

```bash
BLOCKNUM=$( curl -s "https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/blocks?limit=1&order=asc&timestamp=gte:${TIMESTAMP}" | jq ".blocks[].number" )
```

​
(Sample result: `4507206`)

And that's all, you now have your block number!

But let's go one step further to demonstrate that this block number can be used outside of the Hedera mirror node APIs (which are custom, and specific to Hedera).

Let's use this value in JSON-RPC, and obtain the block from there!

Convert that block number to hexadecimal using `printf`.
​

```bash
BLOCKNUMHEX=$( printf "0x%x\n" ${BLOCKNUM} )​
```

​
(Sample result: `0x44c646`)

Make a JSON-RPC request to an instance of `hedera-json-rpc-relay`. If you have one running locally, the endpoint is exposed at `http://localhost:7546` by default. If you don't have that running, [there are other options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76153290/194982).
​

```bash
curl -s -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"2","method":"eth_getBlockByNumber","params":["'"${BLOCKNUMHEX}"'", false]}' http://localhost:7546 | jq ".result"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out [findblock.xyz](https://api.findblock.xyz/#/blocks/get_chain__chainId__block_before__timestamp_) - it's a free API that can perform this search for you for lots of EVM chains including hedera (chain ID 295 if I am not mistaken)

To find the last block before the aforementioned timestamp, you can do:

```bash
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://api.findblock.xyz/v1/chain/295/block/before/1683707272' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
```

the search will be exclusive (by which I mean if there a block with the exact timestamp, it will be ignored and its parent will be returned instead. To make the search inclusive just add `?inclusive`:

```bash
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://api.findblock.xyz/v1/chain/295/block/before/1683707272?inclusive=true' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
```